# Flutter GestureDetector onTapDown/onTapUp, silde finger off pointer

Tags: flutter, pointers, button, gesturedetector

I am having this weird issue with the onTapDown/onTapUp.

I am using the tap down for a voicenote so while holding it down it should record and when lifting it should stop.

However, when I hold the button down and slide my finger off the button's pointer the button's function keeps running. and the only way to stop it is to hold down the button again and then release it.

it there a way to check to see if a user's finger is out of the button's pointer and the stop the recording?

```
GestureDetector(
onTapDown: (_) => _record(),
onTapUp: (_) => _stopRecorder().then((value) => setState(() {})),
child: Icon(_recorder!.isRecording ? Icons.stop : Icons.mic_none_outlined, color: _recorder!.isRecording ? AppColor.mathPink : AppColor.mainBlack),
),
```

Comment: check `onTapCancel` - the docs say: *"The pointer that previously triggered onTapDown will not end up causing a tap.

This is called after onTapDown, and instead of onTapUp and onTap, if the tap gesture did not win."*

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 3):

This was the solution

```
GestureDetector(
onTapCancel: () => _stopRecorder().then((value) => setState(() {})),
onTapDown: (_) => _record(),
onTapUp: (_) => _stopRecorder().then((value) => setState(() {})),
child: Icon(_recorder!.isRecording ? Icons.stop : Icons.mic_none_outlined, color: _recorder!.isRecording ? AppColor.mathPink : AppColor.mainBlack),
),
```